# Netbeans soapUI plugin

Tags: netbeans, soapui, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-plugins

I am trying to install soapUI plugin for Netbeans 6.9.1, but I am getting this message.

```
Some plugins require plugin Lookup to be installed.
The plugin Lookup is requested in version >= 8.8.1 but only 8.3.1 was found.  
The following plugin is affected:       soapUI Web Service Testing
```

Can anybody help? What does this mean? Do I need another plugin?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add a link to the soapUI plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about Netbeans 6.9.1, but in Netbeans 7.2.x this works fine. You can download the Soapui netbeans plugin from [SoapUI NetBeans Plugin at sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/soapui-netbeans-plugin/) and install it using Tools / Plugins / Downloaded / Add Plugin .. and point to the downloaded .nbm file.

Comment: It did not work with netbeans 8.0.2. I downloaded and added it through plugin manager, then my netbeans wouldn't start. Had to delete those jar file in the module directory in order for my netbeans to work again.

Comment: same issue here, guess there is no NB plugin for 8+?